# react-navigation's Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native

I need some community suggestion about react-native app. I am absolutely new and don't understand the few basic differences.

On react-native documentation examples to create StackNavigator suggest
this: import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

I found a lot of people using below style
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

Why people use above two different style? Which one is more appropriate and why?

Isn't react-navigation-stack is part of react-navigation? Is it more of a preference style?

Answer (score 1):

In the v4 of react navigation the navigators were extracted to separate packages, you need to to import:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
```

If you are using the old v3 version the imports should be all from 'react-navigation'.

```
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

More info about the v4.0.0 release [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases/tag/v4.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

I dig into react-navigation documentation and figured out it is because of version.
On internet there is a lot of code using version 1 and some people use version 2 and beyond.